# Vsts & ansibe continuous integration flow

Tags: ansible, azure-devops

I am working on a project where i use ansible for deployement, i would like to create the continuous integration flow with VSTS.

I have create a shell script:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
apt-get update
apt-get install ansible

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "usage: $0 [target [tag [playbook]]]"
  echo "defaults: target='' (all), tag='' (all), playbook='site.yml'"
  echo "example 1: $0"
  echo "example 2: $0 vagrant"
  echo "example 3: $0 mailagent postfix_msa"
  echo "example 4: $0 all linuxusers"
  echo "example 5: $0 dcstage nginx datacollect-server.yml"
  exit
fi

LIMIT=''
TAGS=''
PLAYBOOK='site-win.yml'
ansible-playbook -i ./inventory $LIMIT $TAGS $PLAYBOOK
```

the scripts works fine when i run it from a ubuntu terminal.
Secondly, i try to add new task to vsts as shown bellow [image]

I also use Hosted Linux Preview for agent queue.

The problem here that i need to install ansible on the machine in case the ansible-playbook runs and when i do apt-get the process is hanging  and is not going further so nothing is happening.. 
[image]
Any recommendation how can I fix the ansible & vsts continuous integration flow?

Best Regards,

Comment: Is it possible to rather install via virtualenv + pip? Otherwise you will only be able to use one version of ansible which is not super CI friendly.

Comment: Also what do you mean hanging? Is it possible it's waiting for prompt? Tried "apt-get -y install"?

Comment: i tried pip actually for some reason is throwing an error which i cant understand :(

Comment: i just added a figure where it hangs... i have been waiting for like 1h to it to finish but nothing happen

Comment: I suspect there is another below the one about diskpace saying: "Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y`". Try with "apt-get -y install" I would say. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: true i do also but i cant find this raw and i cant pass parameter to the console.. i cant type anything inside the vsts console

Comment: I meant you could try changing your shell script you showed us above. Watch out you have 2 installs. Both to be checked.

Comment: yeah i got you, i am trying it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(adding as answer after comments):

I suspect there is another below the one about diskpace saying:

> "Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y`"

Try with `apt-get -y install` I would say. Hopefully it helps.